# show popup view controller without segue

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Say I have MVCs for CatViewController, CatDetailViewController, and RegisterViewController; where RegisterViewController is a popup window in the sense that it does not cover the whole screen.

My design is such that from CatViewController a user may segue to CatDetailViewController. However, if the user is not yet registered, the segue is interrupted and the user is asked to register by popping up the RegisterViewController.

My guess is per such design I cannot segue to RegisterViewController. I don’t know if that assumption is true. So does anyone know the common pattern for such design requirement?

FYI: There is another entry point in the app for RegisterViewController.

Comment: A "Modal" segue should work for that. The only problem may be not covering the whole screen, but still, it's probably possible. Or is your problem the logic to decide what segue to call?

Comment: @TiagoLira I can handle the whole screen part. What I need help with is the logic. Again the button click is already responsible for a push segue, namely `CatDetailViewController`. The popup is only conditionally presented instead if the user is not yet registered. I need help implementing the `instead` functionality.

Comment: @TiagoLira a button may only segue to one controller, so modal segue is not an option.

Comment: A button can serve both, if you trigger them by code. I'll write an answer explaining how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to serve two segues with a condition, you can do it by code.

First, in the storyboard, you create the segues from the view controller, and not from the button.
Just connect the view controller to the destination, as you would for the button. The segue connection should appear as "manual". Then, select the segue, and on the right side panel give it an identifier.

Then link the button's "Touch up inside" event to a IBAction method.

Now, in code, use that method to trigger your manual segues:

```
- (IBAction)actionConfirm:(id)sender
{
    if (user.registered)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:nil];
    else
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toRegister" sender:nil];
}
```

Hopefully, this should solve your problem!